# Trouble with printing data from JSON

Tags: android, json

Below I have attached my code. What I'm trying to achieve is printing a String array to a TextView, but I'm getting a NPE before it even gets that far. To describe my code, the array masteriesArray[i][x] holds individual mastery pages, i, and the masteries corresponding to that page, x. The issue I believe I am having is that x is a variable size. I have commented my code to perhaps help it make some sense.

The error is here:

```
   masteriesArray[i][x] = singleMastery.getString("name"); // Error here
   I have confirmed that i = 0, x = 0, and singleMastery.getString("name") is valid and in the case before the error returns "Block."
```

My code:

```
public class MasteriesActivity extends BaseActivity {

    private Spinner spinner;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    public String[][] masteriesArray;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.masteries_activity);
        getActionBar().setTitle("Masteries");
        GetMasteries getMasteries = new GetMasteries();
        getMasteries.execute();
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.mastery_selector);
    }

    class GetMasteries extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

        private String api_key="d96236d2-6ee3-4cfd-afa7-f41bdbc11128";
        String region = MainActivity.region.toLowerCase();
        String id = StatsActivity.sumID;
        String encodedKey = null;
        String encodedRegion = null;
        String encodedId = null;
        String url = null;
        String url2 = null;


        // JSON Node Names
        String TAG_NAME = "name";
        String TAG_CURRENT = "current";


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            try {
                // Encode URL variables
                encodedId = URLEncoder.encode(id, "UTF-8");
                encodedKey = URLEncoder.encode(api_key, "UTF-8");
                encodedRegion = URLEncoder.encode(region, "UTF-8");

                url = "http://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/" + region + "/v1.4/summoner/" + id + "/masteries?api_key=" + api_key;
                url2 = "https://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/static-data/" + region + "/v1.2/mastery?api_key=" + api_key;

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            // Get JSON from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            JSONObject masteriesList = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url2);

            // Get JSON containing Rune Info and cache it
            try {
                ObjectOutput out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(getCacheDir(),"")+"cacheFile2.srl"));
                out.writeObject(masteriesList.toString());
                out.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return json;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
            try {
                // Get JSON Object
                JSONObject masteries = json.getJSONObject(encodedId);

                // Get JSON Array node
                JSONArray mastery = masteries.getJSONArray("pages");

                // Load Saved file
                ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(new File(getCacheDir(),"")+"cacheFile2.srl")));
                String storedMasteryInfo = (String) in.readObject();
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(storedMasteryInfo);
                JSONObject dataObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data");
                Log.i("Mastery data object", dataObject + "");

                // Loop through pages, page names stored in string array
                String[] name = new String[mastery.length()];
                String curr;
                ArrayList<String> masteryPageNames = new ArrayList<String>();

                Log.d("Mastery Length", mastery.length() + ""); // Number of pages user has:  20 Max
                masteriesArray = new String[mastery.length()][];


                for(int i = 0; i < mastery.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = mastery.getJSONObject(i);
                    name[i] = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    curr = c.getString(TAG_CURRENT);

                    JSONArray masteryInfo = c.getJSONArray("masteries");

                    Log.d("Mastery Info", masteryInfo + ""); // Each Individual Page i

                    for(int x = 0; x < masteryInfo.length(); x++) {
                        JSONObject s = masteryInfo.getJSONObject(x);
                        String masteryId = s.getString("id");
                        JSONObject singleMastery = dataObject.getJSONObject(masteryId);
                        try {
                            Log.d("X", x + ""); // 0 then error
                            masteriesArray[i][x] = singleMastery.getString("name"); // Error here
                            Log.d("MasteriesArray[i][x]", masteriesArray[i][x]);
                            Log.d("I", i + "");
                        }
                        catch (JSONException e) {
                            masteriesArray[i][x] = "";
                        }
                    }

                    if(curr.equals("true"))
                        name[i] = name[i] + " [Active]";
                    masteryPageNames.add(name[i]);

                }

                adapter = new ArrayAdapter(MasteriesActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        masteryPageNames);

                spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

                spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long l) {
                        ((TextView) adapterView.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#C49246"));
                        Toast.makeText(adapterView.getContext(),
                                "Page Selected: " + adapterView.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        TextView masteriesText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.masteries);
                        masteriesText.setText("Masteries: " + "\n");

                        for(int j = 0; j<masteriesArray.length; j++) {
                            Log.d("Iteration: ", j + "");
                            masteriesText.append(masteriesArray[pos][j]);
                            masteriesText.append("\n");
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                    }
                });

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (OptionalDataException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (StreamCorruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The JSON:

```
{"23591778": {
   "pages": [
      {
         "masteries": [
            {
               "id": 4211,
               "rank": 2
            },
            {
               "id": 4214,
               "rank": 2
            },
            {
               "id": 4134,
               "rank": 3
            },
            {
               "id": 4124,
               "rank": 1
            },
            {
               "id": 4114,
               "rank": 1
            },
            {
               "id": 4222,
               "rank": 3
            },
            {
               "id": 4112,
               "rank": 4
            },
            {
               "id": 4221,
               "rank": 1
            },
            {
               "id": 4144,
               "rank": 1
            },
            {
               "id": 4122,
               "rank": 3
            },
            {
               "id": 4152,
               "rank": 3
            },
            {
               "id": 4141,
               "rank": 1
            },
            {
               "id": 4111,
               "rank": 1
            },
            {
               "id": 4132,
               "rank": 1
            },
            {
               "id": 4232,
               "rank": 1
            },
            {
               "id": 4162,
               "rank": 1
            },
            {
               "id": 4131,
               "rank": 1
            }
         ],
         "id": 34787712,
         "name": "Blind",
         "current": false
      },
      {
         "masteries": [
            {
               "id": 4212,
               "rank": 2
            },
            {
               "id": 4233,
               "rank": 3
            },
            {
               "id": 4242,
               "rank": 1
            },
            {
               "id": 4214,
               "rank": 2
            },
            {
               "id": 4114,
               "rank": 1
            },
            {
               "id": 4251,
               "rank": 1
            },
            {
               "id": 4112,
               "rank": 4
            },
            {
               "id": 4222,
               "rank": 3
            },
            {
               "id": 4122,
               "rank": 3
            },
            {
               "id": 4262,
               "rank": 1
            },
            {
               "id": 4224,
               "rank": 1
            },
            {
               "id": 4252,
               "rank": 3
            },
            {
               "id": 4132,
               "rank": 1
            },
            {
               "id": 4241,
               "rank": 3
            },
            {
               "id": 4232,
               "rank": 1
            }
         ],
         "id": 34787713,
         "name": "AD/Tank Jungle",
         "current": false
      },
      {
         "masteries": [
            {
               "id": 4242,
               "rank": 1
            },
            {
               "id": 4233,
               "rank": 3
            },
            {
               "id": 4243,
               "rank": 1
            },
            {
               "id": 4211,
               "rank": 2
            },
            {
               "id": 4214,
               "rank": 2
            },
            {
               "id": 4213,
               "rank": 2
            },
            {
               "id": 4114,
               "rank": 1
            },
            {
               "id": 4252,
               "rank": 2
            },
            {
               "id": 4222,
               "rank": 3
            },
            {
               "id": 4113,
               "rank": 4
            },
            {
               "id": 4221,
               "rank": 1
            },
            {
               "id": 4123,
               "rank": 3
            },
            {
               "id": 4262,
               "rank": 1
            },
            {
               "id": 4224,
               "rank": 1
            },
            {
               "id": 4133,
               "rank": 1
            },
            {
               "id": 4234,
               "rank": 1
            },
            {
               "id": 4232,
               "rank": 1
            }
         ],
         "id": 34787714,
         "name": "Mumu",
         "current": true
      },
      {
         "masteries": [
            {
               "id": 4211,
               "rank": 2
            },
            {
               "id": 4121,
               "rank": 1
            },
            {
               "id": 4214,
               "rank": 2
            },
            {
               "id": 4134,
               "rank": 3
            },
            {
               "id": 4114,
               "rank": 1
            },
            {
               "id": 4222,
               "rank": 3
            },
            {
               "id": 4112,
               "rank": 4
            },
            {
               "id": 4144,
               "rank": 1
            },
            {
               "id": 4221,
               "rank": 1
            },
            {
               "id": 4152,
               "rank": 3
            },
            {
               "id": 4122,
               "rank": 3
            },
            {
               "id": 4141,
               "rank": 1
            },
            {
               "id": 4111,
               "rank": 1
            },
            {
               "id": 4132,
               "rank": 1
            },
            {
               "id": 4232,
               "rank": 1
            },
            {
               "id": 4162,
               "rank": 1
            },
            {
               "id": 4131,
               "rank": 1
            }
         ],
         "id": 34787715,
         "name": "vi/j4/wuk/xin/noc",
         "current": false
      },
      {
         "masteries": [
            {
               "id": 4212,
               "rank": 2
            },
            {
               "id": 4353,
               "rank": 3
            },
            {
               "id": 4211,
               "rank": 2
            },
            {
               "id": 4311,
               "rank": 1
            },
            {
               "id": 4362,
               "rank": 1
            },
            {
               "id": 4322,
               "rank": 3
            },
            {
               "id": 4334,
               "rank": 1
            },
            {
               "id": 4332,
               "rank": 1
            },
            {
               "id": 4352,
               "rank": 1
            },
            {
               "id": 4222,
               "rank": 3
            },
            {
               "id": 4314,
               "rank": 1
            },
            {
               "id": 4221,
               "rank": 1
            },
            {
               "id": 4331,
               "rank": 3
            },
            {
               "id": 4324,
               "rank": 1
            },
            {
               "id": 4313,
               "rank": 3
            },
            {
               "id": 4232,
               "rank": 1
            },
            {
               "id": 4342,
               "rank": 1
            },
            {
               "id": 4341,
               "rank": 1
            }
         ],
         "id": 34787716,
         "name": "Support",
         "current": false
      },
      {
         "masteries": [
            {
               "id": 4211,
               "rank": 2
            },
            {
               "id": 4214,
               "rank": 2
            },
            {
               "id": 4124,
               "rank": 1
            },
            {
               "id": 4114,
               "rank": 1
            },
            {
               "id": 4112,
               "rank": 4
            },
            {
               "id": 4222,
               "rank": 3
            },
            {
               "id": 4113,
               "rank": 4
            },
            {
               "id": 4122,
               "rank": 3
            },
            {
               "id": 4152,
               "rank": 3
            },
            {
               "id": 4224,
               "rank": 1
            },
            {
               "id": 4132,
               "rank": 1
            },
            {
               "id": 4142,
               "rank": 3
            },
            {
               "id": 4232,
               "rank": 1
            },
            {
               "id": 4162,
               "rank": 1
            }
         ],
         "id": 34787717,
         "name": "AD Jungle",
         "current": false
      },
      {
         "masteries": [
            {
               "id": 4212,
               "rank": 2
            },
            {
               "id": 4211,
               "rank": 2
            },
            {
               "id": 4121,
               "rank": 1
            },
            {
               "id": 4134,
               "rank": 3
            },
            {
               "id": 4124,
               "rank": 1
            },
            {
               "id": 4114,
               "rank": 1
            },
            {
               "id": 4222,
               "rank": 3
            },
            {
               "id": 4112,
               "rank": 4
            },
            {
               "id": 4221,
               "rank": 1
            },
            {
               "id": 4122,
               "rank": 3
            },
            {
               "id": 4152,
               "rank": 3
            },
            {
               "id": 4141,
               "rank": 1
            },
            {
               "id": 4142,
               "rank": 1
            },
            {
               "id": 4132,
               "rank": 1
            },
            {
               "id": 4232,
               "rank": 1
            },
            {
               "id": 4162,
               "rank": 1
            },
            {
               "id": 4131,
               "rank": 1
            }
         ],
         "id": 34787718,
         "name": "ADC",
         "current": false
      },
   ],
   "summonerId": 23591778
}}
```

Comment: @IllegalArgument Just added it in.

Comment: check this line please  masteriesArray = new String[mastery.length()][]; My guess is it should be something like this: masteriesArray = new String[mastery.length()][5]; according to your json

Comment: @Nate where is json object data in your json

Comment: @Raghunandan From a different JSON. I have added some error details to the post, and I believe the data object to have no impact on the issue, though I could be wrong.

Comment: @IllegalArgument I believe you are on to something. Changing the value there allows the code to continue through, but the issue is that the second value for the 2d array is variable based on how the data is distributed.

Comment: @Nate your way of assiging data to array is complicated try making pojo classes according to the json and use arraylist<yourPojoClass> this is the recommended way to do it in java